# How to get data of textfield which is in EDC file on Tizen?

Tags: tizen

There is one text field in my EDC layout file and i want to get that data on button click. I don't have any idea about that. So, will anyone help me?

Comment: Can you provide the relevant parts of the EDC layout and where you want to get the text data (in a script inside the EDC or the application using the layout).

Answer (score 0):

The code is from the layout and buttons [examples](https://git.enlightenment.org/core/efl.git/tree/src/examples/elementary/). Here are also examples for other language bindings (c, c++, js).

The corresponding [Tizen documentation](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/3.0.0/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__Elm__Button.html) for buttons and layout (native).

The `.edc` layout file with a text part `"title"` and a placeholder/SWALLOW part `"placerholder"` to put a button into.

```
collections {
   group {
      name: "example/mylayout";
      data {
         item: "title" "Layout Example 01";
      }

      parts {
         part {
            name: "example/title";
            type: TEXT;

            description {
               state: "default" 0.0;
               color: 0 0 0 255;
               rel1 {
                  relative: 0.0 0.0;
                  offset: 0 0;
               }
               rel2 {
                  relative: 1.0 0.5;
                  offset: -1 -1;
               }
               text {
                  text: "bla";
                  size: 16;
                  font: "sans";
                  min: 1 1;
                  ellipsis: -1;
               }
            }
         }
         part {
            name: "placleholder";
            type: SWALLOW;

            description {
               state: "default" 0.0;
               fixed: 1 1;

               rel1 {
                  relative: 0.0 0.5;
                  offset: 0 0;
               }
               rel2 {
                  relative: 1.0 1.0;
                  offset: -1 -1;
               }
            }
         }
    } 
}
```

To setup the layout, add a button and read the text of the `"title"` part in good old C looks like this (not a complete working example, as I can't test it):

To setup the layout:

```
Evas_Object *win, *bt, *layout;

   // Create a window ( I don't know if this works in tizen like this.)
   win = elm_win_util_standard_add("layout", "Layout");
   elm_win_autodel_set(win, EINA_TRUE);

   // Adding layout and make it fill the window
   layout = elm_layout_add(win);
   evas_object_size_hint_weight_set(layout, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND);
   elm_win_resize_object_add(win, layout);

   elm_layout_file_set(layout, "/path/to/layoutfile.edj", "example/mylayout");
   evas_object_show(layout);
```

To add a button:

```
   bt = elm_button_add(layout);
   elm_object_text_set(bt, "Get the text");

   // put the button into the layout
   elm_object_part_content_set(layout, "placeholder", bt);

   // add clicked callback to button, pass the layout reference as data pointer
   evas_object_smart_callback_add(bt, "clicked", _btn_cb, layout);
```

Button callback:

```
static void
_btn_cb(void *data, Evas_Object *btn EINA_UNUSED, void *event_info EINA_UNUSED)
{
   // data pointer is the layout reference
   Evas_Object *layout = data;

   // with the layout reference we can get the text of part "title"
   const char *text = elm_object_part_text_get(layout, "title");
}
```

The code is from the layout and buttons [examples](https://git.enlightenment.org/core/efl.git/tree/src/examples/elementary/). Here are also examples for other language bindings (c, c++, js).

The corresponding [Tizen documentation](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/3.0.0/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__Elm__Button.html)